# Is there any way to allow photoshop to download required fonts automatically or Manually?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts

While i download some **PSD** file and open using photoshop so many fonts are not installing my system.
so i check each and every font and google it and download it. it takes so much of time.
So **Is there any way  to allow photoshop to download required fonts automatically or Manually at single click?**

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible, and there are many reasons for that or for why you wouldn't want that.

Most quality fonts are not free. Would you allow Photoshop to simply purchase the first version of the font you want, regardless of the price or the version? Different foundries have different versions of fonts. You want to make sure that you use the same version; sometimes a project was started with a different version of a font you already own.

Also, when you install a font directly in your OS' font folder it is available for every application; which means that it's loaded in the RAM every time you boot your computer, and you end up with a list that can be very long when you try to choose a font. If you have different versions of a font, it can also create conflicts.

The best solution is to have some font management software. This will allow you to manage your fonts by project, as well as activate/deactivate them as you need. when I open a document that has missing fonts, it automatically opens my font manager to allow me to locate and activate the fonts. I use FontExplorer Pro, but I'm sure there are many others out there.

Comment: I dont think the fonts are exactly loaded to ram just because they are in teh system fonts folder-

Comment: They are stored in RAM in order to be readily available; similar to plugins that are always running. Although RAM is more plentiful now than it used to be, it will severely affect your system if you put a few thousand fonts in the system folder. Many years ago, we used to remove all the unnecessary system fonts to get that tiny bit of extra. The rule of thumb was to leave the ones with city names as they were absolutely necessary to boot the system.

Comment: you sure about this, when i hook to my resorces in debugging that font is loaded only once needed. OTOH photoshop and illustrator seem to need many of them all the time.

Comment: That's what I was taught, and I've seen many computers that slowed down a whole lot after the entire font library was put in system fonts. I looked and can't find a proper source to prove or disprove it. Only other forums, people having performance issues and other stack exchange answers. Even the article on that topic on Microsoft support says "The articles are produced by Future Publishing Limited. Microsoft is not responsible for the content, accuracy or opinions expressed in these articles." Tell me if you find reliable sources, but my experience tells me that too many system fonts is bad.

Comment: Might depend on OS version

Comment: Yes, it might depend on that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually ***yes***, that is possible now with the most recent version of Photsohop.  But not for all fonts, only Adobe's Typekit fonts. For all other fonts, you'll need to download manually and install on your system.

Adobe Photoshop CC and some other Creative Cloud applications are now integrated with the AdobeTypekit website.  If you need a font, you can click on *Type > Add fonts from Typekit*, which will launch the Typekit website in your browser, where you can Sync them to your Creative Cloud account. Then the fonts will then be automatically downloaded and available in your applications.

Obviously, you will be limited to Adobe's own Typekit fonts for this functionality to work.  Other fonts from other vendors have nothing to do with Adobe, but despite this limitation, it's a still an absolutely wonderful new feature.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it depends on the fonts you need to download but as others have stated Photoshop CC can sync fonts from Typekit. If you're using a Mac and looking to sync fonts, have them activated/deactivated automatically, and the like then you might consider a font manager of some kind.

My only recent experience with one is RightFont which not only manages your local font files and syncs/downloads your Typekit and Google's font library, you can also connect it to many of the cloud storage services or even a local shared folder to sync fonts you own.

https://rightfontapp.com/faq.html